# diameter and radius of a regular graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-mathematics, computer-science

I am trying to find the radius and diameter of a regular graph $G$ with $d(v_i) < (n-1)/2$. I know for $d(v) \geq (n-1)/2$, $\rm{diam}(G) \leq 2$ and $\rm{radius}(G)=\rm{diam}(G).$  If we are not taking the complete graphs.

I am unable to do the same for the regular graphs  of valence smaller than  $(n-1)/2$.

Are there any regular graphs $G$ for which the diameter and radius are equal and have valence smaller than $(n-1)/2$. ? Can anybody help me. Any hint or suggestion to proceed? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

There are such graphs.

I'll give you a hint.

**Hint 1.** Which graph is the first one you should think of when trying to find a counterexample or disprove something?

**Hint 2.** 10 vertices, 3-regular.

Comment: on 10 vertices with regularity 3,  petersen graph is the example. but can we generalise the above statement of my question?

Comment: Another example is the Hoffman-Singleton graph and the 5-cycle. Hence try looking at regular graphs with diameter two.

Comment: thanks...then it means that theoretically we cant get any generalized result? i mean can we put restriction on number of vertices so that it satisfies the condition?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Are you asking if there are infinitely many such examples?

Comment: I am sorry for that. I just mean that like we did for d(v) $\geq$ (n-1)/2, can we prove or disprove that radius and diameter will be equal if d(v) $\leq$ (n-1)/2

Comment: @monalisa Well you have such regular graphs for which the radius matches the diameter and regular graphs for which this is not true. Does that help your question?

Comment: sir i have theoretically proved the theorem for d>=(n-1)/2, and for d$<$(n-1)/2 i have examples where radius & diameter are equal.. but can it be proved theoretically. I mean what result do we get if the regular graph is of degree$<$ (n-1)/2. strictly less than. Can we conclude theoretically whether radius and diameter will be equal or not? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

1- Cube

2- consider three triangles and three vertices and connect every vertex of triangles to one of the three vertices. $\text{Diam}=R=k=3$